# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined while writing Kotlin Wrapper for matter.js

Tags: javascript, kotlin, matter.js

I want to use [matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/) in one of my kotlin/JS projects. For doing this, I use a wrapper with external references to the matter.js classes. A test file to reproduce the error is here:

```
package engineEmi

import org.w3c.dom.CanvasRenderingContext2D
import org.w3c.dom.HTMLElement
import kotlin.browser.document
import kotlin.browser.window

external object Matter {
    val engine : Engine
    val render : Render
    val world : World
    val bodies : Bodies
}

external class Engine{
    fun create() : Engine
    fun run(engine : Engine)
    val world : World
}

external class Render{
    fun create(body: HTMLElement?, y : Engine) : Render
    fun run(render : Render)
}

external class Bodies{
    fun rectangle(posX : Int, posY : Int, width: Int, height: Int) : Body
}

external class Body{
}

external class World{
    fun add(world: World, elements : Array<Body>)
}

object EngineEmi{
    fun main() {
        var World = Matter.world
        var Bodies = Matter.bodies

        var engine = Matter.engine.create()
        var render = Matter.render.create(document.body, engine)

        var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
        var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);

        World.add(engine.world, arrayOf(boxA, boxB))

        Matter.engine.run(engine)
        Matter.render.run(render)
    }
}
```

It compiles well but throws the following error in the browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
>       at EngineEmi.main (engineEmi.js:449)
>       at main (engineEmi.js:28)
>       at engineEmi.js:505
>       at engineEmi.js:508
>   EngineEmi.main @ engineEmi.js:449
>   main @ engineEmi.js:28
>   (anonymous) @ engineEmi.js:505
>   (anonymous) @ engineEmi.js:508

But I believe, `engine` is well defined and should be linked to the external JS class.

Can anyone assist here?

**EDIT:**

For reference purposes: This is the JS-implementation of the Engine with the .create() Method : [LINK TO GITHUB](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/src/core/Engine.js)

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem with another library I'm trying to create a Kotlin wrapper for.